# Many duplicate queries when using image tag in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using Wagtail v1.13.1 for my website project. I'm trying to optimize db queries...

**models.py**

```
class ProductPage(Page):
    ...
    main_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True
    )

class ProductIndexPage(Page):
    ...
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductsIndexPage, self).get_context(request)
        all_products = ProductPage.objects\
            .prefetch_related('main_image__renditions')\
            .live()\
            .public()\
            .descendant_of(self)\
            .order_by('-first_published_at')
        paginator = Paginator(all_products, 10)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            products = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            products = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context['products'] = products
        return context
```

**product_index_page.html**

I'm outputting product card in a for loop. Each product card has this tag:

```
{% image product.main_image fill-600x300 %}
```

But still getting a separate call to db for each image.

Models are connected in this way:

**ProductPage** --fk--> **wagtailimages.Image** <--fk-- **wagtailimages.Rendition**

The question is: What is the proper way to prefetch renditions and eliminate duplicate db queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
prefetch_related('main_image__rendition_set')
```

This is assuming that the image templatetag can use the prefetched values correctly.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that Rendition model defines fk to Image model this way: image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='renditions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)