# Wagtail "prefetch" image urls for multiple pages

Tags: python, django, wagtail

My page contains links to multiple Wagtail pages.  The pages come from a query in my code, which looks something like this:

```
SomePageModel.objects.in_site(site).live()
```

Now, each page can have an image, so I'm presenting them in the template:

```
{% for page in pages %}
    {% if page.header_image %}
        <div class="text-center">
            {% image page.header_image width-400 class="img-fluid" %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <h3>
        <a href="{{page.url}}">
        {{ page.title }}
        </a>
    </h3>
{% endfor %}
```

The image rendering results, however, in a separate SQL query per page in the result! So, if the query produces 20 pages, we'd have extra 20 hits to the DB!  Is there a way to sort of prefetch these image URLs in one query, best in a join with the original page query? Or generate them without SQL?  The whole page is presumably dynamic, so caching alone isn't the answer.

The model in question:

```
class SomePageModel(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('blockquote', BlockQuoteBlock())
    ])
    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        get_image_model_string(),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name=_('Header image')
    )

    settings_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('go_live_at'),
                FieldPanel('expire_at'),
            ], classname="label-above"),
        ], 'Scheduled publishing', classname="publishing"),
    ]
```

Comment: Is that "sort of looks like this" query yours or Wagtail's query?

Comment: This is my query, I can modify it as needed

Comment: Then please add the Subpage model. Especially what `header_image` is.

Comment: Added the definition

Answer (score 0):

So `get_image_model_string()` returns a model to import as "image model", that model has an image field and probably a **str**() method that returns the image url. And that is causing your problem. In order to fix it, you need to select the related image model in the join:

```py
SomePageModel.objects.in_site(site).select_related('header_image').live()
```

If this doesn't fix your problem, please post the image model's definition.

### Wagtail's image tag

So, wagtail indeed does a query inside an image tag. It's not a good practice, especially for tags that may be used inside a loop. In their defence though, they try to cache the data in the "rendition cache".

The source is in `wagtail.images.models.AbstractImage`, `get_rendition()` method and the issue is that the template tag determines what the correct rendition is for the image. So they do an extra query for the exact rendition and prefetch_related is useless because of it. If you iterate the renditions or know ahead of time what rendition you need, then you can avoid the lookup.

If the number of renditions per image is limited in practice, it may actually pay off to filter the renditions in python, since they are already available. In that case, I'd advize to stimulate that practice, by providing your own template tags like "thumbnail", "hero_image", "article_interstitial", etc.

You would change this code:

```py
        try:
            rendition = self.renditions.get(
                filter_spec=filter.spec,
                focal_point_key=cache_key,
            )
```

to

```py
found = None
for r in self.renditions.all():
    if r.filter_spec == filter.spec and r.focal_point_key == cache_key:
        found = r
        break
```

And in your view you would:

```py
SomePageModel.objects.in_site(site).select_related(
    'header_image'
).prefetch_related(
    'header_image__renditions'
).live()
```

Comment: I will check, thanks.  The image model is vanilla Wagtail :)

Comment: Fair enough, it eliminates the extra query from wagtail_images, however it looks like the image tag still makes a separate query:

SELECT "wagtailimages_rendition"."id",
       "wagtailimages_rendition"."filter_spec",
       "wagtailimages_rendition"."file",
       "wagtailimages_rendition"."width",
       "wagtailimages_rendition"."height",
       "wagtailimages_rendition"."focal_point_key",
       "wagtailimages_rendition"."image_id"....

Comment: This looks like a related question, but it has no working answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487578/many-duplicate-queries-when-using-image-tag-in-wagtail

Comment: OK, I gave up on the {% image %} tag altogether and started loading the renditions manually in a single query. This way I have one query only, no matter how many pages in the result. I render <img > myself now

Comment: Added some food for thought :)

Comment: I realised that, after reading some Wagtail code.  In the end I fetch the right renditions myself and pass the final image url to the template, so I don't use the image tag at all.  There is room for improvement in Wagtail...